# Abstracting Primary key implementation

Tags: oop, orm

So am a few months into a project and I realize that the PKs I chose might not fit enhancement planned for version 2. I also find that moving to either a compound PK or a surrogate PK will require a code change to virtually every part of the system.

For instance my DAL has GetPerson(string PersonID) methods that will need to take other types of parameters to function. Also most of the web pages take querystrings with PKs embedded in them (i.e. /GetPerson?PersonID=BILL)

It got me thinking that I wish I implemented some encapsulation where I protected myself from PK changes. Have abstract methods for placing and reading a PK from a querystring. Likewise instead of passing native types to the DAL, pass a PersonPK object and hide the implementation.

In theory I like the idea, I'm just not sure in practice, it's possible to prevent this from becoming a "leaky abstraction". For instance, once it's time to generate DB calls, I have to crack open the PK object. And there still is going to be dozens of statements to rewrite.

So to my question....Does anybody successfully use PK abstraction in their projects? Has it saved you time? What are the keys to implementing this successfully?

EDIT:
Some of the replies suggest to me that I wasn't clear on something.

I was never suggesting that I create some abstract primary key column in the database. I was merely contemplating that the Business Logic and front end code be designed in a way that was resistant to PK refactoring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I wish I implemented some
>   encapsulation where I protected myself
>   from PK changes.

The encapsulation you're looking for is the simple use of a surrogate key. That is: an identifier generated by the database (not the end user) to uniquely identify a row of data. They are usually auto-incrementing integers and sometimes GUIDs.

My rule of thumb: If a piece of data stored in the database has the slimmest chance of even appearing in front of the end user (much less being available for editing) then DO NOT use it as a primary key! An example: An email address can uniquely identify a user in a system. Yes, it can be used as a pkey but!

- What if the user wants to change his/her address? You have to update simultaneously every table where the email address is the foreign key!
- Consider the index bloat on each table that contains that primary key!
- Consider the performance hit of comparing two strings instead of two integers to link two rows in a simple join!

Many devs go as far as automatically creating a surrogate key for every table in the db. This is actually good practice, especially if surrogate keys don't feel "natural" to you right away.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such term as "PK abstraction".

There are natural primary keys, and there are surrogate primary keys.

You want a [surrogate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key) primary key. Bite the bullet and make the change, otherwise you will forever have a big mess.

Answer (score 1):

I've attempted this a number of times and concluded my endeavors by simply throwing it all away. Once I accepted the use of strictly a single column / property for all my keys, all the time, it not only simplified code and made it future proof, it's also quite easy to refer to those records in the DB. Have multiple columns / properties that identify a record as unique? OK, sure, keep those, but still have a single, unique column / property for that row / object.

Ex:

Users having social networks - a many-to-many relationship with objects of Users and SocialNetworks. Normally your database would have a lookup table expressing those relationships:

```
user_id | network_id
```

So the uniqueness is expressed by user_id+network_id ... however, simply slap another column in there for uniqueness thusly:

```
user_network_id | user_id | network_id
```

It's so much easier to "unwrap" these single-column, unique identifiers when it comes to rendering your SQL. It's also easier to refer to your in-memory objects with this method.

Answer (score 0):

A. Unlike OOP, the proper design of your database back-end does not include the concept of "abstraction" for something like a PK. The Proper definition of Primary keys is the core of solid database design. By definition, PK's are concrete within the scope of the table to which they refer. The pain of not getting this key element of a relational database design correct the first time is what you are experiencing now.

B. The relational database model is premised on the idea that the information in each table is unique, and identifiable by its primary key. There are some long-standing rules ("Normalization") which have formed the basis for identiifying proper PK's and developing a strong, scalable table structure.

C. As Mitch Wheat observes in his post, abstraction of a PK is not possible.

D. I strongly recommend digesting what the others have said in this thread, doing some research on Primary keys and normalisation, and biting the bullet. You will be glad you did when you approach versions 3, 4, 5  etc. of your application code.

A final note - you will find many arguments for and against the use of auto-incrementing PK "identity fields" vs "Natural keys". Personally, I favor the auto-incrementing ID - THere is virtually no chance that it will change in the future. Also, I strongly believe in using a PK that is menagingless to the user.